# Convert from list to list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, set

I have the following list

```
a = ['Bananas', 'Ananas', 'Peach', 'Grapes', 'Oranges']
```

and want to have it as a list of dicts like

```
b = [{"fruit": "Bananas"},{"fruit": "Ananas"},{"fruit": "Peach"},{"fruit": "Grapes"},{"fruit": "Oranges"}]
```

How can that be done?

Comment: Those are dictionaries, not sets, but yes it can be done. `b = [{"fruit": fruit} for fruit in a]`

Comment: There is no rule that uses {} instead of () in a set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:
`b = [{'fruit':f} for f in a]`

Answer (score 4):

These are actually dictionaries not sets inside the list, you can give a try to list comprehension:

```
a = ['Bananas', 'Ananas', 'Peach', 'Grapes', 'Oranges']
b = [{"fruit": x} for x in a]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a key `fruit`, you should use list comprehension:

```py
b = [{ 'fruit': x } for x in a ]
```